# Wierd MySQL/PHP error

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to get a list from my MySQL database, which normally works fine. But today I'm getting this error `Fatal error: Call to a member function setFetchMode() on a non-object in "Way too long path to file here"`.

This is my PHP code:

```
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;port=3306;name=erty', 'erty', 'Ops, that my password ...');

$result = $conn->query("SELECT name FROM mod_devs");
$result->setFetchMode();
foreach ($result as $row) { 
    echo '<tr><td>'.$row['name'].'</td></tr>';
}
```

Now, you probably understand my goal :)

Comment: Found the error, in the connection i write name=erty not dbname=erty! Sorry for taking up your time :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the error. In the connection I wrote `name=erty` not `dbname=erty`!

Sorry for taking up your time :(

Answer (score 1):

Generally `Call to a member function setFetchMode() on a non-object` means that $result is not available. Probably because of MySQL error - either in connection or query. Check `if($conn)` or `if($result)`.

Comment: $conn returns true, but $result return false which is wierd since the same query is working just fine in PMA

Answer (score 1):

You still need to fetch the result...
So instead of foreach....do while...

```
  while ($row = $result->fetch()) {
  //your code here

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you maybe need prepare not query

```
     $result = $conn->prepare("SELECT name FROM mod_devs");
```

or this

```
    $result->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```